# How to extend the vuejs app instance on specific laravel blade view

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am very new in vue.js please help me on this, by default Laravel 5.3 comes with vue integrated, in `assets/js/app.js` file it initializes the vue instance.

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

I can make some global vue component and require them before initialization code in `app.js`.

But I want to have some data, method and components unique on specific page `(.blade.php)`. for example, I need one form on login view and another list of posts in a different view.

How can I extend the vue app instance on the specific page and add local components etc.

I have `@stack('scripts')` in my layout. I wanted to do something like this

```
@push('scripts')
<script>
  app.src = "{{ $me->avatar }}";

  app.methods = {
    imageuploaded (src) {
        this.src = src;
    }
  }
</script>
@endpush
```

Please help how I can do it, or any other best way to deal with this problem.